# How to explain magic scientifically?

Tags: magic, technology, nanotechnology, balancing-magic-systems

I'm writing a story and I'm having trouble finding credible explanations for certain elements of it.

Basically, in the late 2090s, technology has advanced to the point that it is possible to manipulate matter through a specific technology as if it were “magic”, for example controlling natural elements, making objects levitate, creating luminosity, casting lightning, hardening and freezing objects, accelerate or decelerate the speed of bodies, creating force fields, etc.

My idea is that all this is only possible through a device made or that works on the basis of a fictional ore that I created.  Not all people would be able to use this technology either, on the contrary, only a low percentage of the world's population would be able to do so because they have a region in the brain that allows them to "connect" to the device via brain waves or something.

My difficulty is thinking about how this would all work.  I know the results I want to get but I don't know how to explain the process.  What does this device do to manipulate reality and matter in this way?

In “The Irregular at Magic High School”, a novel that I took several inspirations for my story, people can invoke magic through a device that works via “thought particles” that rewrite the essence of an object/phenomenon and alter the event, or simply by controlling these particles.  I wanted to move away from the concepts created for this novel to avoid plagiarism and give my story more originality.

I know it sounds like a very difficult question but that's basically it.  If it were possible to use magic via technology, what would that technology need to do to alter reality?

Comment: Yes, but we use specific technologies and devices for each of these cases.  What I asked is exactly how to explain the execution of all these phenomena through a portable device, such as a cell phone or a watch.  “How can I run at the speed of a car without being in one?”  “How can I fly without being in a flying machine?”  “How can I freeze something instantly without putting it in the freezer?”.  There is also the issue that most of these abilities would be used in combat.

Comment: "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" Arthur C. Clark. Regardless of what the answer is, any technology will seem like magic to people who have never seen such a thing before.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Reminds Aurora people in Asimov's 'Foundation and Earth'. That people had conductors in their brains able to canalize energy of a vaste area, then they used it for their own purposes, in situations like you mentioned.

Comment: Magic is inherently unknowable by definition.  If you can explain it at every point, it isn't magic, it's technology.  Magic may be repeatable, but sooner or later, you will come to a point where you can't explain it.

Comment: “Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.”. Just try imagining a medieval peasant interacting with an Ipad,they would see it as a magic piece of metal that shows images like our own eyes!

Comment: Oh yeah, by the way, I had the same struggle with a history of mine, but the explanation I was satisfied with (besides "advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic") was that everything has energy, and the way this energy is transported, transformed or manifested (kinect, thermal, electricity and other types of energy) is controlled by the human brain, so they aren't really violating the laws of physics, just "bending" them in their favor. How humans can do that with their minds? Well, *that's* the magic.

Comment: You have answered your own title question: A new ore explains magic scientifically. This question can't be answered as is because what does "alter reality" even mean? Does it mean cats can breathe magma or the moon came alive and want's to join your church? Please tell us what "alter reality" means *very specifically* so we can talk give an objective answer. I am voting to close until it is edited down.

Comment: In any setting with Magic, Wizards are just physicists.

Answer (score 3):

**Swarms of Nanobots**

Hundreds of microscopic machines are powered by (or made of) this special magical ore that you have created. While it's largely still in the development stage, nanobots are still fully within the realm of plausibility for the real world, and the way they'd operate could be very close to magic.

The idea is roughly like this.

The reason why only a small portion of the population can use the technology is that the technology itself is expensive, and the nanobots are controlled by a surgical implant that needs to be carefully inserted. In other words, the difference between magic and non-magic users boils down to money. Some people can afford fancy technology and some people cannot.

Swarms of the tiny robots, commanded by the controls in the brain, are then able to carry out any instruction that the user gives them by forming any number of combinations.

If the bots themselves are microscopic, they can be used to go into the very makeup of the objects they are targeting and change their chemical construction, disassembling and reassembling molecules with ease.

*Electromagnetism*

A lot of the problems you are proposing could easily be solved with powerful enough control over Electromagnetism. Levitation can be accomplished at least when dealing with metals, an electric current could be made to shoot "Lightning" at any opponent, etc. Light can be created using an electric current as well, and a "force field" would just be a powerful enough repulsive force to move an object out of the way. Have the nanobots be able to mess with the force of electromagnetism, and they could accomplish most of the requirements.

*Swarm Mechanics*

Have the robots move in unison, able to form whatever shape the user desires, sticking together most likely through the magnetic forces that were mentioned earlier.

Imagine being able to make a sword seemingly out of nowhere, or perhaps a car or a jet or anything else the user desires? All of this would be possible with a large enough swarm of semi-intelligent nanobots.

They could grab onto objects, hold things in place, or make physical shields to block attacks if a force field is not an option. Nanobots moving against each other rapidly might be able to create lots of friction, thus generating the heat necessary to use fire attacks. If the bots are hard to see unless working in large clouds, it would easily give the illusion of levitation.

*Molecular reconstruction*

If the robots are small enough to reconfigure things on the microscopic level, then they could reach into the very makeup of an item and change it rapidly. They might not be able to change the elements that make up the molecules, but they would be able to tear things apart molecule by molecule and then replace those with new ones.

For example, mixing iron with particles in the air could create rust (Fe2 O3). You would be able to rapidly turn shiny new metal into something unrecognizable.

It's still mostly a sci-fi idea at this point, but nanobots are incredibly cool technology that would very easily substitute magic.

Comment: If you have nanobots, let *them* construct the control logic in situ, rather than requiring dangerous brain surgery. But some brains adapt more readily to this addition than others, and nobody knows why…

Answer (score 3):

### A new undiscovered science field.

While we, early XXI century real-world humans have never found any evidence of, say, a fifth Force, your late XXI century fictional humans did.

Just like gravitational waves were considered a myth by many just a decade ago, your scientists found evidence (developed the tech to detect) of a strange force that *"defied the laws of physics"*.

There's no such thing as something that *"defies the laws of physics"*. The new empirical evidence just expanded it. As quantum mechanics defied the Newtonian physics of old, so the 2090's people are on the verge of a new scientifical revolution.

What their new widget, an extremely sensitive detection device found was a force that explains a lot of parnormal phenomena. Parapsychology is back in force, and its findings are not as inconclusive as before.

The new ore they identified is a massive source of this force, and as interest spikes, new deposits are discovered all over the world and solar system. It is probably very weak and useless unless refined and enriched, like uranium. But once it is, the potency increases exponentially.

Maybe the ore came in a meteor shower that crossed the Solar System. The hunt for meteorites can be a good source of conflict.

The people who can connect to this force all have a strange neuron knot that reacts to ore in their brains, like a pigeon brain do to magnetic fields. Having an enriched ore piece on their bodies allows them to manipulate this force.

With that they can create paranormal phenomena, tapping into this new Force.

Take the enriched ore away from them and they are ordinary humans.

You can even say there's a computer interface that helps them manipulate this force, like Tatsuya's CADs.

Answer (score 1):

The most important aspect of this is to keep the rules for "magic" consistent. If you can do that, you have any number of possible explanations to pull from, depending on the sort of story you're developing.

These include:

1. The "real world" is a simulation, and that simulation can be modified while running. In some variations, it's not even necessary to have a computer performing the simulation (see Greg Egan's *Permutation City*).
2. There are more fundamental laws of physics that aren't easily perceivable with the technology (and mundane matter) that we currently have available to us (see Greg Bear's *Moving Mars*).
3. This takes place in an entirely different universe than the one you and I inhabit, which operates under similar, but different laws of physics (this is even hypothetically possible within our own reality).

Answer (score 0):

### How to make magic agreeable with a scientific setting

Science does not disprove the existence of the human soul or God or any sort of spirituality, it has simply failed to provide an adequate interface to test them so far.  Science likes to avoid what it can not test; so, many people who call themselves scientists label things as false when the more scientific thing to do is actually call it inconclusive.

So to add magic to a sci-fi setting, you need to identify where science has brushed aside everything as inconclusive in nice big broad strokes.
Let's take the following things that modern science likes to ignore due to lack of ways to test:

1. **Science can not explain your own personal first person perspective.**  As modern science explains the human brain, it is like a machine that follows commands and adapts to its environment via regressive processes.  This creates useful patterns of data that result in behaviors, but it no way explains why you exist in this world through the perspective of this singular meat sack.  While it explains how you think, it does not explain how you have any personal experience of this world.  Your brain may be doing all the hard work by putting together the story you see, but behind all that machinery there is YOU, and that you is "watching" the story that your body creates from a state of being that exists outside of our well understood 4 dimensions of reality. If you go by just what we understand about computers and neuroscience, all things should be 3rd person to your perspective meaning that you should not exist as any one of the people in this reality.
2. **The universe is created.**  We know that is was created because we have tracked its origin all the way back to the moment of the "Big Bang" where it all started. While this alone does not prove intelligent design, it certainly allows for this possibility.
3. **The Universe is Hyperdimensional** To solve for all observable phenomena in a causality consistent way, String Theory states that the universe must consist of at least 10 dimensions.  This means that the universe is exponentially more complex than anything modern science can observe or test making most of reality that we predict to exist, completely inconclusive.
4. **Creators rarely create things in more dimensions than they can fathom** ... but they often create things in fewer dimensions.  Since #2 says that the universe is created and #3 says that creation is at least 10 dimensions of complexity, this means that anything that may have made this universe is itself likely aware of and able to effectively comprehend 10 dimensional reality. To the creator, we could be like paintings, simplified down to fewer dimensions for simplicity sake, but still technically existing in all the dimensions of his reality.
5. **A thing can exist in more dimensions than it can perceive.**  Consider a simple robot that navigates via a camera looking down at the ground.  The robot exists in the Y-axis, but has no way of seeing, understanding, testing for, or manipulating the Y-axis; so, it can never have awareness of its whole self.

#### How this works into a magic system:

The human concepts of god(s) seems erroneous because they are inconsistent with 4 dimensional reality because according to religion we were created by a being who was himself created by the one who made the universe, and we were created by the being who made the universe, and that being is simultaneously 1 and 3 distinct persons... and 12... and thousands.  He is strict and jealous, but also forgiving and kind. One possible explanation of this is that all these apparent contradictions come out of having a maker that is 10 or more dimensional. He is simultaneously all the things that we can imagine he is, and many things we can not even comprehend.  He is not just everything that is, he exists in a state of everything that can be.

Picture a cube.  You can see 3 faces, but 3 faces are hidden to you.  Now picture a [Dekeract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) (a 10-dimentional hypercube).  You will still only see 3 faces, but it will have 11,517 faces hidden to you.  So people all explain God in very different and often contradictory ways because we can only see such a small aspect of our creator at a time.

But the even harder thing to understand is that we are also 10-dimentional beings.  We fully exist in his world because that is where he made us.  We see so little of ourselves and our environment that we have no clue about most of what we truly are.  We are like his little robots all stuck looking down, because that is all we were designed to do... but your magic ore allows us to modify ourselves.  Like adding new cameras to a robot so that it can see the whole room that it exists in, once a robot understands its whole environment, it can manipulate things it could not see before.

Now instead of being able to take the reality around us and manipulate it in 4-dimentions, we can manipulate it in all 10.  We can see that the air is both hot and cold, and instead of letting 4-dimentional reality tell us what it is, we simply rotate or slide that part of reality to whatever possible state we want it to be.  Murphy's Law says "what-ever can happen will happen if we make trials enough", but this becomes supplanted by Wizards' Law "What ever can happen can be made to happen when I will it so."

#### So why are so few people able to be wizards?

It's simple.  We can upgrade the hardware, but we are still running on human brain power.  To be a wizard you must be able to reason in more than 4 dimensions, but we are not designed to understand our whole reality.  Only a small number of people, given a "3rd-eye" device can even comprehend 1 maybe 2 extra dimensions if they work really hard at it, the more mentally gifted you are in what we would call theoretical spatial mechanics, the more of this newly seen reality you can grasp and control.  And once you see 6-dimentions of space, and learn to comprehend it, that means your "sprite" can manipulate those other dimensions as though you are taking them in your physical hands and moving things around.

If you want to make an object levitate, just slide it over in the 9th dimension so that it so that it no longer intersects with gravity. Want to create a forcefield, just reach around a few of the extra dimensions and pinch off space-time so that anything that passes through that area of space is sucked into a wide, but paper thin black hole. Want to transmute something, just turn it in the dimension of space that regulates molecular bonds... so on and so forth.

This could also make for an interesting class of Clerics that are separate from Wizards.  They can't figure out the physics enough to manipulate extra dimensions the way that Wizards can, but they can comprehend enough extra realities to get a much better view of god(s) whom they can learn to communicate with and ask for favors. Or you could make your setting conclusively without God(s) or extra-dimensional beings, but still with humans that have extra-physical selves that can manipulate other dimensions.  Once you delve into hyper-dimensional awareness, modern science is so blind you can put pretty much anything you want in there.

Comment: hmm your title seems to be incompatible with *"Science can not explain your own personal first person perspective."*. Science is about real things and spirituality is part of your first person perspective, imho.. something that one person can experience, while the other person won't experience it. Science is not about subjective insights, imho.

Comment: Also I wonder how you would prove the big bang was caused by anything, let alone created by some entity.

Comment: @Goodies The whole point of this answer is that it is all reality.   The Scientific Method is not about real things, but about testable things.  Right now, science can not explain your own personal first person perspective, because it is missing any perception of a huge part of the puzzle.  Spirituality is simply the best way to explain in English that I know of that your self extends way beyond what we consider the material world.

Comment: Since we don't know what those other 6+ dimensions hold, you can speculate any number of possibilities.  The closest to informed speculation you can make though is that they are the source of things we have observed, but not been able to test or understand.  People throughout history have described interactions with beings outside of our understood reality.  Scientists often write this off as delusions without any actual proof they are not happening simply because they don't know how to prove if they are happening.

Comment: Science tries to label everything as proven true or false, which biases modern science against those things that are unprovable... but once you increase human awareness to all of reality a LOT of unprovable things will suddenly become provable.  God can be proven true or false.  Souls can be proven true or false. Etc.  This answer is working on the assumption that once we got to that point, we proved spiritually to be true because if it is false then it means humans have no means to act on the other 6 dimensions to achieve magic like abilities.

Comment: `science can not explain your own personal first person perspective` totes agree. The hard problem of consciousness is still a hard problem indeed. `Spirituality is simply the best way to explain in English...` this is where we differ, I think. What does "spirituality" explain at all? Does it offer a model to understand how consciousness functions, or is it just a magic word that has no explanatory or predictive power at all?

Comment: @TKoL Spirt, in this since explains the part of you that exists outside of 4-d reality that you can't see.  Going with the robot example above, understanding just your material body is like understanding your have 4-wheels on the ground that move you around.  Understanding a whole Robot is much more complex than that, but the robot that suddenly becomes aware of not just what is below it, but in every direction, suddenly has new ways of understanding itself and its environment

Comment: A robot could intuit that it has an engine that moves its wheels... but have zero understand about what an engine really is or how it works

Comment: That's fine and good as a postulate, but do you actually have more *understanding* from that? Can you use it to make predictions about the real world? Does it modify your mental model about how the real world functions at all? Or is it rather a label that you put on things that you actually CAN'T explain, and therefore becomes more of an 'anti-explanation' than an explanation?

Comment: 'Spirituality' seems like an anti-explanation to me. It's relegated to the unexplainable, rather than being an explanation. It's a word that we say to signify 'look no further, you can't find anything here'. It's not an explanation, because it adds no understanding. It's synonymous, it seems, with 'mystery'. Which is okay, some things are mysterious, but saying 'its mysterious' isn't an explanation.

Comment: @TKoL That is my point about why magic remains rare.  Most people can't expand their understanding and abilities just by seeing the whole of reality... but those who can understand it will be able to manipulate it IF a part of them exists there.

Comment: @TKoL I am not saying "Here is where science says magic is" so much as "Here is where science say magic could be."